# Understanding changes in the C# vtable when referencing nugets in different versions

Tags: c#, nuget, vtable

In our product we have a UI library that is referenced by many modules. The UI library and the modules are distributed as NuGet packages. Modules reference the UI library.
A base app references the modules and also references a version of the UI library. Not every module is using the latest release of the UI library, so the base app can actually have a higher UI library version than the one used in modules.

In the UI library we provide a `LibraryBasePage` that inherits from a Xamarin.Forms `ContentPage`. A bugfix requires to override the OnAppearing inside the LibraryBasePage.

```
## Before the change:

public class LibraryBasePage : ContentPage
{
    // no overriding of OnAppearing is done
}

## After the change:

public class LibraryBasePage : ContentPage
{
  override OnAppearing()
  {
      base.OnAppearing();
      FixSomething();
  }
}
```

### The issue

A new version of the UI library is released. The new release is integrated in the base app, while the modules that are referenced in the base app still reference an older
version of the UI library.

In cases where a page from a module inherits the `LibraryBasePage` *and* overrides OnAppearing, we notice that the fix which was added to the `LibraryBasePage` does not work.

```
public class ModuleBasePage : LibraryBasePage
{
    override OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        ...
    }
}
```

Only when updating to the newest UI library, both inside the module *and* in the base app, the fix works.

### Question

Why is it not sufficient updating the UI library just in the base app? Our assumption was that the NuGet dependency resolution uses the fixed UI library version because it is
on top of the dependency graph. When debugging the ModuleBasePage, the LibraryBasePage.OnAppearing method is never called. Our feeling is that this behavior can be explained with how vtables are created and used. How does the vtable of ModuleBasePage look like, when (a) updating to new release of the UI Library in modules *and* base app and (b) using only the new release of the UI lib in the base app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that `base.OnAppearing();` refers directly to `ContentPage.OnAppearing`, not to `LibraryBasePage.OnAppearing`, because it did not exist when the module was built.

`base.` does not use `callvirt`, it uses `call`, so no lookup on the vtable is done. Given the newer version is actually loaded into the app, I think this is technically unverifiable, but it seems no error is actually thrown.

As you can see from [this sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgZgATIEzoLIHsYBXCAUwCEBDAZ1IAVKBzU9EdAGTACMAnSngJ5VaDZgFgAUAG9J6OZgz4AbqR48wMFsgAs6APIA7AIIAHE6X5gDjABQBKWfJkT5r9FxqkAdIdPnL1vYA3I5yAL6SoQroyqrqmpi6vmYW6tZY9lHObvIetD7GKQGMGXYhLvIRElWSaJg4nLz8Qp6iLGwAwvgGwKQ9bZLZ0bFqGlpJhf5ptg4VQ6553slTVjPl4ZI1EnXY6F09fcAD0lF1SmA8wESUEIn6k6mrmRVy8+hbrmcXVzd3y4/pZ6uN5VKpAA), the line of code is calling directly to `ContentPage`

```
call instance void ContentPage::OnAppearing2()
```

The only way to prevent this is to have *every* `virtual` function specifically overridden, even if there is no intention at the moment of doing anything with it.

```cs
public class LibraryBasePage : ContentPage
{
  override OnAppearing()
  {
      base.OnAppearing();
   }
}
```

[ECMA-335 Section III](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf) states:

> **3.19 `call` – call a method**
>
> *..snip..*
>
> 2. It is valid to call a virtual method using `call` (rather than `callvirt`); this indicates that the method is to be resolved using the class specified by method rather than as specified dynamically from the object being invoked. This is used, for example, to compile calls to ―methods on `super` (i.e., the statically known parent class)

Interestingly enough, the **Verifiability**  section there does not specifically exclude the case of calling `base.base.Method`, so it's unclear if it is actually unverifiable. C# certainly does not allow it.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer. Still digesting it though. I think I found an explanation, why `base.` does not use `callvirt` [here](https://www.levibotelho.com/development/call-and-callvirt-in-cil/): "An example of when this occurs is when an overriding method calls a base implementation. Were the call to be made with callvirt, the runtime would end up re-calling the derived implementation which would then re-call the base implementation and so on and so forth until a stack overflow occurred."

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why it is used. That was essentially what that snippet from the spec is saying.